# Hardware Debugging Help On Home Build Computer

Tags: windows-7, boot, motherboard, power-supply

I built my first computer six years ago: ASUS motherboard, 6 core AMD CPU, 2 SSDs, CD ROM, 64 bit Windows 7 server, 32GB RAM.  It ran beautifully for six years - until last Monday.

I turned on my computer after work and logged in after the machine booted up.  I was browsing in Chrome when the monitor went dark.  I could smell that something had burned.  I turned the machine off and on - no beeps, no nothing.

I assumed the power supply fried, so I bought an identical replacement from Newegg.  It arrived tonight.  I reconnected the new power supply as best I could.  But when I powered it on the behavior was the same: nothing.  No beeps, no fans, no activity whatsoever.

What is my next step?  What component might I replace to try to bring this machine back to life?  If it requires someone more capable than me, what would be the best questions to ask?

Comment: If it is an older machine, the first thing I would check would be for any bulging capacitors on the motherboard.

Comment: Great thought Matt. I did a visual and didn't see any, but I may have missed one.

Comment: Have you tried a different monitor? Does the monitor power on like a light on it or the PC or see or hear anything indicating the PC is powered on? Have you tried a different electrical outlet, and surge protectors or how about power cable to the wall receptacles? Make sure you're not overlooking something obvious and test the electrical outlets as well with another device if needed that you know works from another electrical socket, Quick thoughts...

Comment: Thank you. Yes I checked all those things. Everything is perfect except for my machine. Motherboard check to come.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've blown something on your motherboard might want to check your kettle lead as well because it may of caused your blow out.

Comment: Thank you, @Englishman.  I'll give it a look.  I'm going to be looking for bad capacitors, listening for "no RAM" beeps after removing my RAM, etc.  Good advice.

Comment: oh god those beeps give me nightmares hope you find the issue :) keep us posted